# node.js script fails - TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'on' - Mac to Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, node.js

when I attempt to run this [uvsensor.js script](https://github.com/plotly/workshop/blob/master/arduino/uvsensor/uvsensor.js) from this [plot.ly tutorial](https://plot.ly/arduino/uv-sensor-tutorial/) I encounter this error message.  What is the best way to resolve it?

```
uv-sensor-tutorial $ node uvsensor.js
1421612122362 Device(s) /dev/cu.usbmodem1411
1421612125588 Connected /dev/cu.usbmodem1411
1421612125588 Repl Initialized
>> { streamstatus: 'All Streams Go!',
  url: 'https://plot.ly/~micahstubbs/46',
  message: '',
  warning: '',
  filename: 'uv sensing nodey arduino!',
  error: '' }

/Users/m/workspace/arduino-projects/uv-sensor-tutorial/uvsensor.js:76
    refLevel.on("data", function() {
             ^
TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'on'
    at /Users/m/workspace/arduino-projects/uv-sensor-tutorial/uvsensor.js:76:14
    at /Users/m/node_modules/plotly/index.js:87:17
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/m/node_modules/plotly/index.js:255:9)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: The problem is clearly in the repository code, introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/plotly/workshop/commit/43bdfba5e52d893fde78c797200534b9d9e88db0). In these cases, you should [report an issue](https://github.com/plotly/workshop/issues/new) in their repository before outsourcing the work to Stack Exchange. The repository maintainers are much more likely to know what they intended and where they gone wrong than us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to resolve it is to find out why `refLevel` is being assigned `0` instead of the object you think it should be.

Comment: this is the answer - the object is `ref_3V3`, not `refLevel`, which is a variable. sent plot.ly a pull request to fix this https://github.com/plotly/workshop/pull/3